# How can I block a URL in a WebView?

Tags: android, url, block

public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);


    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    setContentView(webview);


}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {

        return true;
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://stackoverflow.com")) {

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to block an url in the `WebView`, how to block the url? This code doesn't work.

Comment: I try to follow the code but i failed to block the url

Comment: Depend on where do you test it, in new device > Android 24, you may also want to override this method: 
`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, WebResourceRequest request)`.

Comment: @HooiHuan Did you manage to block the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You should return true if you want specific behavior according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).

> Returns true if the host application wants to leave the current
>   WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

Answer (score 0):

block all the urls working solution even i tried it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView wv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wv1 = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(wv1);
    wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wv1.loadUrl("http://www.kart.epizy.com");
    wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    wv1.setClickable(true);
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shuldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do something with the event here
        return true;
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     //return false to allow urls or add your condition like
       //return url.equals("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=kArt+Developers");
        return true;
    }
} }
```

Comment: I follow the code u give, but i still can access to the website, it cant block too

Comment: Hi Hooi Huan, please share your full web view code first.

Comment: This doesn't work for POST requests because this method won't be called. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that whith this:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://stackoverflow.com")) {
            view.stopLoading();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

When you intercept the request in shouldOverrideUrlLoading overriden method and detect the URL to be blocked, stopLoading will stop loading the website and you will get a block on this URL,
Now you are detecting the URL but not managing it